# New to Python, NameError: name is not defined (after creating class)

Tags: python

Not sure why this is happening or how to fix it. I'm new to Python and any help is appreciated.

```
class Sentence:
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s= s
        x=s[:-1]
        self.L= list(x.split())
    def __getitem__(self,idx):
        return (self.L[idx])


s= Sentence('What a beautiful morning!')

getitem(s, 2)
```

NameError: name 'getitem' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__):

> #### `object.__getitem__(self, key)`
>
> Called to implement evaluation of `self[key]`. ...

By implementing `__getitem__`, you can use the bracket notation to retrieve items:

```
s[2]
```

Or by calling `__getitem__` explicitly (I wouldn't do it):

```
s.__geitem__(2)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that solves it. Loving these beginner mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Blender has a nice straightforward answer but for what it's worth, I notice that you typed:

```
getitem(s, 2)
```

It looks like you were thinking something like this:

```
def __getitem__(self, x):
                 |    |
        ---------     |
        |  ------------
        v  v
getitem(s, 2)
```

It may or may not be of some benefit to you for me to note that when you define a method for a class and you pass `self` as an argument, you're specifying the instance of that class, i.e. the object, as `self`. So when you do `self.s = s` you're saying "set this object's `s` to the parameter `s`'s value."

`self` does not become one of the arguments in parentheses; you can think of that argument as being a special one outside of the parentheses.

```
def __getitem__(self, x):
                 |    |
------------------    |
|             ---------
v             v
s.__getitem__(2)
```

Again, as Blender said, since `__getitem__()` is a special function (which is kind of like an operator override for subscript), you shouldn't call it directly - just a heads up!

For more, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained).